# Is fetching a whole array at once from the smart contract a good idea?

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript

```
// @dev An array that contains all the Cids of IPFS Content
string[] public cidsArray;

// Unique Cid to Content struct.
mapping(string => Content) public contentsMapping;


    function getTotalContentCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return cidsArray.length;
    }

    /*  
    @dev
    If you have a public state variable of array type,
    then you can only retrieve single elements of the array via the generated getter function. 
    Therefore the entire array can only be returned by a function  
    */

    // @notice Function that returns entire cid array.
    function getCidArray() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return cidsArray;
    }
```

So is it a good idea to get the whole array at once using that **getCidArray()** function, or is it better to get the **array length** and iterate through the generated getter function for the same array?

On the frontend ofcourse (next.js)

**Which way is better and why?**

It looks like both works, but what if the array contains a million elements?

Answer (score 1):

Most RPC provider has a gas limit for `eth_call` t prevent spam and overloading of their infrastructure. Usually, it's about 2x-3x of the block gas limit. So as long as the gas of the view function is below your RPC providers limit, it should be fine.

If the array length won't reach a really high value, then it should be okay to fetch it all at once. But if the array can get arbitrarily large, it's a better idea to implement some sort of pagination. It's generally a good practice too as it makes sure things won't break in the future too.