# The simplest way to return a list of items + gas limits on long lists when using pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2?

Tags: arrays, gas-limit, the-graph, abiencoderv2, version-pragma

This question has two parts.

I would like to return a list of items from my smart contract in a simple way, ideally a one-liner solution, something that I consume on the front-end.

I tried some of the products listed here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/top-10-indexed-blockchain-data-apis-providers-3a43da97e54c

*(but still dind't find a perfect match)*

The objection / difficulty / concern that I have with using The Graph:

- emit ChangeName(...)
- emit ChangeDescription(...)

It feels like additional effort of emitting all the events, then writing handlers to reconcile the current state.

I just want to get the current list of items.

#### 2. Is there a gas limit? (front-end only)

A really simple solution seems to use `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2`

```
function getOrganisations() public view returns(Organisation[] memory) {
   return organisations;
}
```

It generates ABI, my front-end is able to load the data.

> view functions don't actually consume gas when they're called from off-chain (because they don't change state)

Will MetaMask / Infura complain about the block size / amount data to return if the array grows to big?

I guess I'll have to try but if this is documented somewhere - please let me know

**EDIT / UPDATE**:

This is where I read about the limits: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/121223/2524

> Most RPC provider has a gas limit for `eth_call` t prevent spam and overloading of their infrastructure. Usually, it's about 2x-3x of the block gas limit. So as long as the gas of the view function is below your RPC providers limit, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most RPC Provider will enforce a `gasLimit` for  `eth_call` as DOS Protection. For instance, Alchemy has a limit of [550 mio.](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/gas-limits-for-eth_call-and-eth_estimategas) and Infura has a limit of [300 mio.](https://docs.infura.io/networks/ethereum/json-rpc-methods/eth_call)

You can create a view function that retrieves the total number of organizations stored in the array and and another function that retrieves multiple organisations with a single call using [multicall](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Multicall.sol/).

```
function numOrgs() public view returns(uint256) {
    return organisations.lenght;
}


function getOrganisations(uint256 idx) public view returns(Organisation memory) {
   return organisations[idx];
}
```